# Why JavaScript is parsing the array named "name" to string

Tags: javascript, arrays

When defining the array:

```
var name = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
```

And displaying it on the console :

```
console.log(name);
```

We get a string!

```
"A,B,C"
```

But when defining the array with another name:

```
var haha = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
```

We get an array when displaying "which it should do"!

```
(3) ["A", "B", "C"]
0: "A"
1: "B"
2: "C"
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Why is that happening?

Comment: `console.dir(haha)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`name` is a global property which is part of the [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name#Notes) object. It has a special property which converts its values to strings by calling their `.toString()` method:

> `window.name` will convert all values to their string representations by
>   using the toString method.
>
> - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name#Notes)

So, when you set your global variable to `var name`, you're setting the global variable `name` on the window which will convert your array to a string. You can use `let` or `const` to not add it to the `window`, and thus keep it as an array:

```js
const name = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(name);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a collision with `window.name`, the variable is being ignored.

```
var name = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
console.log(window.name);
// A,B,C
```

Instead:

```
let name = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
console.log(name);
```

That sets up a proper local variable.